# Add icon to django-admin's navbar

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, tailwind-css

[image]

**I want add icon for every app and models, How should i do?
and how change the default app name for django-admin.**

I using tailwindcss and daisyUI and fontawesome for custom